# evaluate an expression inside R RefClass instance environment

Tags: r, class, eval

I'm dealing with a new issue that I did not have before (it was running fine before).
R shows an error if I run a method of a class from inside of class if I did not run this before from outside of the scope of instance.
I did not know how to phrase my question, please read the example:

```
> setRefClass(
+   Class = "testClass",
+   methods = list(
+     test = function(){
+       print("test")
+     }
+   )
+ )
> instance = new("testClass")
> eval(substitute(test()), instance) 
Error in test() : could not find function "test"
> # WHY DID I GET ERROR !!!!

> instance$test()
[1] "test"
> eval(substitute(test()), instance)
[1] "test"
> # IF I RUN THE METHODE ONCE FROM OUTSIDE, I DON'T GET ERROR!!!!
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have many instances of the same class, and I have a long script to run on each of these instances. it is just running several methods on each instance. 
I wanted to avoid `instanse$` in my code, so I was running the expression without `instanse$` in front of each method, by running the expression inside of the instance scope.

Answer (score 0):

after some experimentation, it looks like R should mount methods to the Class before using it.

However, I could define a function in the Class `field` and use it immediately.

Here is an example:

```
> setRefClass(
+   Class = "testClass",
+   fields = list (
+      test = "function"
+   ),
+   methods = list(
+     initialize = function(){
+       test <<- function(){
+           print("test")
+       }
+     }
+   )
+ )
> instance = new("testClass")
> eval(substitute(test()), instance)
[1] "test"
```

I'm not sure exactly, what is the differences, but it works as I expected.